# pass variable from hover to offhover

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, hover

### http://jsfiddle.net/MwQbE/

i have the jQuery Below but i cant get the variables to pass to the second function

```
$("img").hover(function(){
    var $image = $(this);
    var $imageNowWidth = $image.width();
},function() {
    // get variable value for $image and $imageNowWidth   
});​
```

When testing on jsFiddle it doesn't work, what can I do to pass the variable to the second function?

Comment: Just declare them in the second function as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply define those 2 variables outside `.hover` and then you can use them inside mouseleave function. See below,

```
var $image, $imageNowWidth;
$("img").hover(function(){ //mouseenter
   $image = $(this);
   $imageNowWidth = $image.width();
},function() {            //mouseleave
    //$image and $imageNowWidth is accessible HERE
});​
```

Just want to clarify that `this` will be available inside `mouseleave` function so you can do the same or more w.e you are doing inside `mouseenter`

Answer (score 2):

Define `getter` and `setter` for `image` and `imageNoWidth` as below,

```
var getImage, getImageNoWidth;
$("img").hover(function(){
   $image = $(this);
   $imageNowWidth = $image.width();
    getImage = function(){
        return $image;
    };
    getImageNoWidth = function(){
        return $imageNowWidth;
    };
},function() {
    // get variable value for $image (getImage()) and $imageNowWidth (getImageNoWidth())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable outside, so it is accessible in both functions.

```
var image;
var imageNowWidth;
$("img").hover(function(){
    image = $(this);
    imageNowWidth = $image.width();
},function() {
    // get variable value for $image and $imageNowWidth   
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the variable directly on the jquery object using the jquery 'data' method :

```
$("img").hover(function(){
    var $image = $(this);
    $image.data('imageNowWidth',$image.width());
},function() {
    var previousImageWidth = $(this).data('imageNowWidth');
    // do whatever you want to do with the width       
});​
```